# How to create Custom filter options in wp_list_table?

Tags: wp-list-table

I used `wp_list_table` class to create my custom table in the backend. It's working fine.

Now, I want to add filters like in the below image. 
[image]

Here is my existing code to render admin table with my custom information's.

```
if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Kv_subscribers_list extends WP_List_Table {

    function __construct(){
        global $status, $page;                

        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular'  => 'notification',  
            'plural'    => 'notifications',   
            'ajax'      => false      
        ) );        
    }

    function column_default($item, $column_name){
        switch($column_name){
            case 'email':
            case 'date':
            case 'common':          
            case 'unit_id':          
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    function column_email($item){       
        $actions = array(
            'email'     => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&email_id=%s">E-mail</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'email',$item['id']),
            'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&delete_id=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['id']),
        );

        //Return the title contents
        return sprintf('%1$s %2$s',
            /*$1%s*/ $item['email'],          
            /*$2%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }

    function column_cb($item){
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
            /*$1%s*/ $this->_args['singular'],  
            /*$2%s*/ $item['id']                
        );
    }

    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
            'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
            'email'=>__('Date'),  
            'date'=>__('Date'),  
            'common'=>__('Common Alert'),           
            'unit_id'=>__('Unique ID')
        );
        return $columns;
    }

   public function get_sortable_columns() {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'email'   => array('wp_user_id',false),     //true means it's already sorted
            'date'    => array('date',false),
            'common'  => array('common',false)
        );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }

   public function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = array(
            'delete'    => 'Delete',
            'email'     => 'Email'
        );
        return $actions;
    }

   public function process_bulk_action() {
        global $wpdb; 
        $notifications_tbl = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter';

        if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {
            foreach($_POST['notification'] as $single_val){
                $wpdb->delete( $notifications_tbl, array( 'id' => (int)$single_val ) );             
            }
            $redirect_url =  get_admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=subscribers' );
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url); 
            wp_die('Items deleted (or they would be if we had items to delete)!');
        } 
        if( 'email'===$this->current_action() ) {           
                $result_email_ar = implode("-",$_POST['notification']);
            $redirect_url =  get_admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=kvcodes&ids='.$result_email_ar  );
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);        

            wp_die('  ');
        }       
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb; //This is used only if making any database queries
        $database_name = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter' ;
        $per_page = 10;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $database_name ORDER BY id DESC";

        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);        

        $this->process_bulk_action();

        $data =  $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A );

        function usort_reorder($a,$b){
            $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'title'; //If no sort, default to title
            $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; //If no order, default to asc
            $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); //Determine sort order
            return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; //Send final sort direction to usort
        }
       // usort($data, 'usort_reorder');        

        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();        

        $total_items = count($data);

        $data = array_slice($data,(($current_page-1)*$per_page),$per_page); 

        $this->items = $data;

        $this->set_pagination_args( array(
            'total_items' => $total_items,                  //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page'    => $per_page,                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
            'total_pages' => ceil($total_items/$per_page)   //WE have to calculate the total number of pages
        ) );
    }
}//class
```

and

```
echo '<form method="post">';
    $mydownloads = new Kv_subscribers_list(); 
    echo '</pre><div class="wrap"><h2>Subscribers<a href="'."http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&add_new=true" class="add-new-h2">Add New</a></h2>'; 
    $mydownloads->prepare_items(); 
    $mydownloads->display(); 
    echo '</div></form>';
```

Now, I want to make the filters like

> All || Published || Trash

I need to create a custom filter like this.

Answer (score 17):

**Code**

```
class Kv_subscribers_list extends WP_List_Table {

function __construct(){
    global $status, $page;                

    parent::__construct( array(
        'singular'  => 'notification',  
        'plural'    => 'notifications',   
        'ajax'      => false      
    ) );        
}

protected function get_views() { 
    $status_links = array(
        "all"       => __("<a href='#'>All</a>",'my-plugin-slug'),
        "published" => __("<a href='#'>Published</a>",'my-plugin-slug'),
        "trashed"   => __("<a href='#'>Trashed</a>",'my-plugin-slug')
    );
    return $status_links;
}

function column_default($item, $column_name){
    switch($column_name){
        case 'email':
        case 'date':
        case 'common':          
        case 'unit_id':          
            return $item[$column_name];
        default:
            return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
}

function column_email($item){       
    $actions = array(
        'email'     => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&email_id=%s">E-mail</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'email',$item['id']),
        'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&delete_id=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['id']),
    );

    //Return the title contents
    return sprintf('%1$s %2$s',
        /*$1%s*/ $item['email'],          
        /*$2%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}

function column_cb($item){
    return sprintf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
        /*$1%s*/ $this->_args['singular'],  
        /*$2%s*/ $item['id']                
    );
}

function get_columns(){
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />', 
        'email'=>__('Email'),  
        'date'=>__('Date'),  
        'common'=>__('Common Alert'),           
        'unit_id'=>__('Unique ID')
    );
    return $columns;
}
public function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'email'   => array('wp_user_id',false),     //true means it's already sorted
        'date'    => array('date',false),
        'common'  => array('common',false)
    );
    return $sortable_columns;
}
public function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = array(
        'delete'    => 'Delete',
        'email'     => 'Email'
    );
    return $actions;
}

public function process_bulk_action() {

    global $wpdb; 
    $notifications_tbl = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter';

    if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {
        foreach($_POST['notification'] as $single_val){
            $wpdb->delete( $notifications_tbl, array( 'id' =>    (int)$single_val ) );             
        }
        $redirect_url =  get_admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=subscribers' );
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url); 
        wp_die('Items deleted (or they would be if we had items to delete)!');
    } 
    if( 'email'===$this->current_action() ) {           
            $result_email_ar = implode("-",$_POST['notification']);
        $redirect_url =  get_admin_url( null, 'admin.php?page=kvcodes&ids='.$result_email_ar  );
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);        

        wp_die('  ');
    }       
}

function prepare_items() {
    global $wpdb; //This is used only if making any database queries
    $database_name = $wpdb->prefix.'newsletter' ;
    $per_page = 10;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $database_name ORDER BY id DESC";

    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);        

    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $data =  $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A );

    function usort_reorder($a,$b){
        $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'title'; //If no sort, default to title
        $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; //If no order, default to asc
        $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); //Determine sort order
        return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; //Send final sort direction to usort
    }
   // usort($data, 'usort_reorder');        

    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();        

    $total_items = count($data);

    $data = array_slice($data,(($current_page-1)*$per_page),$per_page); 

    $this->items = $data;

    $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $total_items,                  //WE have to calculate the total number of items
        'per_page'    => $per_page,                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        'total_pages' => ceil($total_items/$per_page)   //WE have to calculate the total number of pages
    ) );
}
}//class
```

**Admin Page & Rendering Sample**

```
function o_add_menu_items(){
    add_menu_page('Plugin List Table', 'Sub', 'activate_plugins', 'subscribers', 'o_render_list_page');
} 
add_action('admin_menu', 'o_add_menu_items');

function o_render_list_page() {
    $mydownloads = new Kv_subscribers_list();
    $title = __("Subscribers","my_plugin_slug");
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>
            <?php echo esc_html( $title );?>
             <!-- Check edit permissions -->
             <a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=subscribers&add_new=true' ); ?>" class="page-title-action">
                <?php echo esc_html_x('Add New', 'my-plugin-slug'); ?>
            </a>
            <?php
            ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <?php $mydownloads->views(); ?>
    <form method="post">
    <?php 

        $mydownloads->prepare_items(); 
        $mydownloads->display();
    ?>
    </form>
<?php
}
```

**Explanation**

We need to override `WP_List_Table` class method [get_views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L378) to get status links on the top.By default it is an empty array.

[views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L388) method of `WP_List_Table` uses [get_views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L378) to display list of those links that we return in the [get_views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L378) as an associative array with separator `|`.

We can also override [views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L388) method to have more control , for example if we want to change separator.

Take a look at how other list tables are using that. For instance check [WP_Posts_List_Table](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L264).

After you have overridden the method then place `$mydownloads->views();` .be sure to escape all and internationalize strings.

**Using Filter**

We can use `views_{$this->screen->id}` filter once we have added [get_views](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L378) method.
Assuming `toplevel_page_subscribers` as screen id

```
add_filter('views_toplevel_page_subscribers','my_plugin_slug_status_links',10, 1);

function my_plugin_slug_status_links($views) {
   $views['scheduled'] =  "<a href='#'>Scheduled</a>";
   return $views;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the cleanest way is to use `extra_tablenav` like @metita described it

Answer (score 5):

Well, I know this is quite late, but since this is the first result in google when searching for WP_List_Table filtering, I must tell you that there's `extra_tablenav` function available to be overrode in your class extension:

```
class Kv_subscribers_list extends WP_List_Table {

    function extra_tablenav( $which )
    {
        switch ( $which )
        {
            case 'top':
                // Your html code to output
                break;

            case 'bottom':
                // Your html code to output
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to output in both sections just ignore the switch and set your HTML code straight at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php
class Kv_subscribers_list extends WP_List_Table {

    function extra_tablenav( $which )
    {
        switch ( $which )
        {
            case 'top':
                // Your html code to output
                global $wpdb, $wp_locale;

                    $extra_checks = "AND status != 'auto-draft'";
                    if ( ! isset( $_GET['status'] ) || 'trash' !== $_GET['status'] ) {
                        $extra_checks .= " AND status != 'trash'";
                    } elseif ( isset( $_GET['status'] ) ) {
                        $extra_checks = $wpdb->prepare( ' AND status = %s', $_GET['status'] );
                    }

                    $sql = "
                    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR( create_date ) AS year, MONTH( create_date ) AS month
                    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."audio_record
                    WHERE 1 = 1
                    $extra_checks
                    ORDER BY create_date DESC";
        
                    $months = $wpdb->get_results(
                        $wpdb->prepare(
                            $sql
                        )
                    );
                    $month_count = count( $months );

                    if ( ! $month_count || ( 1 == $month_count && 0 == $months[0]->month ) ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $m = isset( $_GET['m'] ) ? (int) $_GET['m'] : 0;

                    $wp_query = add_query_arg();
                    $wp_query = remove_query_arg('m');
                    $link = esc_url_raw($wp_query);
                    ?>
                    <div class="alignleft actions">
                    <select name="m" id="filter-by-date">
                        <option<?php selected( $m, 0 ); ?> value="0" data-rc="<?php _e($link); ?>"><?php _e( 'All dates' ); ?></option>
                    <?php

                    foreach ( $months as $arc_row ) {
                        if ( 0 == $arc_row->year ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $month = zeroise( $arc_row->month, 2 );
                        $year  = $arc_row->year;

                        $wp_query = add_query_arg('m', $arc_row->year . $month);
                        $link = esc_url_raw($wp_query);

                        printf(
                            "<option %s value='%s' data-rc='%s'>%s</option>\n",
                            selected( $m, $year . $month, false ),
                            esc_attr( $arc_row->year . $month ),
                            esc_attr( $link),
                            /* translators: 1: Month name, 2: 4-digit year. */
                            sprintf( __( '%1$s %2$d' ), $wp_locale->get_month( $month ), $year )
                        );
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = jQuery('#filter-by-date option:selected').data('rc');">Filter</a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                break;
                break;

            case 'bottom':
                // Your html code to output
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and for action query, you can add code in

> public function prepare_items()

> or funtion get_customers
> $this->items = self::get_customers($per_page, $current_page);

```
<?php
        //public static function get_customers($per_page = 20, $page_number = 1) 


        if (!empty($_REQUEST['m'])) {
            $search = $_REQUEST['m'];
            $year = substr($search,0,4);
            $month = substr($search,4,5);

            if(!empty($year)){
                $sql .= ' And YEAR(create_date)="' . $year . '"';
            }
            if(!empty($month)){
                $sql .= ' And MONTH(create_date)="' . $month . '"';
            }
        }
```

This is example for get form my database
When click Filter button will go to url from data-rc

[image]